# Vim Syntastic Cannot show any error in JSHint

Tags: html, vim

I just start using Vim. I have Syntastic installed. But Syntastic cannot show any error.

For instance, I use Syntastic to edit HTML and use JSHint to check for error:

When I type SyntasticInfo, the following shows up:

```
Syntastic info for filetype: html
Available checker(s): jshint
Currently Available checker(s): jshint
```

But still no error comes up.

The main point is: I understand that there should be a gutter on the left side of the vim after installing Syntastic. And this does not show up. Why the gutter not show up?

Here is my vimrc

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
  let opt = '-a --binary '
  if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
  if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
  let arg1 = v:fname_in
  if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
  let arg2 = v:fname_new
  if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
  let arg3 = v:fname_out
  if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
  let eq = ''
  if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
    if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
      let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
      let eq = '"'
    else
      let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
    endif
  else
    let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
  endif
  silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction

call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
call pathogen#helptags()

set lines=50 columns=200

colorscheme darkblue

filetype plugin on
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete

let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1

let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jslint']
let g:syntastic_html_checkers = ['tidy']

let g:gitgutter_sign_column_always=1
```

After some thought, I now tried to use htmltidy. I install htmltidy by:

```
npm install htmltidy -g
```

But still no result. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you expect JSHint to show HTML errors? JS errors? Both?

Comment: JSHint doesn't validate HTML files, it only validates JS files.

Comment: @romainl Yes I know JSHint is mainly for JS. But when you look at vim syntax_checkers folder. In html folder, there is really jshint. But my first order problem right now is that the Syntastic's gutter is missing. What have I done wrong?

Comment: JSHint is *only* for JavaScript. It can indeed extract the JavaScript from your HTML but it *only* validates the JavaScript, not the HTML. If there's no error in your JavaScript you'll get no error signs, no location list, no error message in the cmd-line, nothing. Now, it's possible that something else is missing or misconfigured (How should we know? You didn't show us your configuration or provide a limited test case…) but we must start with clearing up your expectations.

Comment: @romainl Hi, thanks for your comment. I have changed to use htmltidy instead. I have also put up my vimrc. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a sample HTML file with errors?  Did you try `:SyntasticCheck`?  I think I have to update syntastic:  I do not have a `:SyntasticInfo` command.

Comment: @benjifisher I just randomly make some error for vim to check. Like <h1>brian</h3>, sth like that. But when I call :SyntasticCheck, nothing occurs.

Comment: I promptly get a response from Syntastic when I use that errorful line.  When I check with `:scriptnames` I see that the last two files `:source`d are `syntastic/syntax_checkers/html.vim` and `syntastic/syntax_checkers/html/tidy.vim`.  You should see something similar, even though we are using different versions of Syntastic.

Comment: @benjifisher Thanks for response. I really can't see anything. After extensive googling, I know that Syntastic would have a gutter on the left of the screen, showing all the errors. But I can't get the gutter in the first place.

Comment: If syntastic was not working for lots of people, then googling might work.  Since it does work for most people, you have to figure out what is going wrong for you.  Instead of googling, try debugging.  Instead of stopping with the one visible symptom, try to understand the sequence of events that starts with `:SyntasticCheck` and ends with markers for the errors.  A good place to start is with `:scriptnames`.

Comment: @benjifisher Really thank for your help. I finally manage to get it working after much tinkering. I have added let g:syntastic_mode_map = {'mode' : 'passive'} to my vimrc.